# How do I add WorkflowControllEndpoint with HttpBinding to all Workflow services hosted on IIS with Appfabric

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, workflow-foundation, appfabric

By default AppFabric adds WorkflowControllEndpoit with NetNamedPipeBinding.
In my environment I need to manage workflows from another server which means that I cannot use net.pipe.

**How do I add a WorkflowControllEndpoint on HttpBinding?**

Please note that I allow users to **dynamicly add workflows** so I'm looking for a way to add endpoint to all workflows hosted by AppFabric.  tag in web.config is not good for me.

### Attempt 1:

Using behaviour to add endpoint. I've had problems adding WorkflowControllEndpoint. I've add following to behavior

> var host = (WorkflowServiceHost)serviceHostBase;
>   host.AddServiceEndpoint(new WorkflowControlEndpoint(new
>   WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(host.BaseAddresses[0] +
>   "/Control")));

that compiles and runs but when I make request to this endpoint I'm getting

```
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost/WorkflowServices/xx.xamlx/Control.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

I guess that's because endpoint wasn't added and it goes to a default endpoint which doesn't accept Soap

### Attempt 2

Disabling net.pipe - That forces AppFabric to bind to WSHttpBinding for WorkflowControllEndpoint but then I get wornings in *Persistence window* like 
`workflow persistence is not fully functional because the net.pipe`

What functionality do I loose ?